# How to get closest input using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, queryselector

Trying to improve on my javascript.  How do you get the closest input checkboxes.

I have a fiddle but I am stuck on how to get the group of checkboxes for a div.  My goal is the get the group of checkboxes for the bike1 div then loop to deselect them.

```
document.querySelector('.bike1 input').closest('div')
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6b7umjf/3/)

```js
const checkAllButton = document.getElementById("checkAll");
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("first");
let isChecked = false;
checkAllButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  isChecked = !isChecked;
  //check or uncheck inputs
  for (checkbox of checkboxes) {
    if (isChecked) {
      checkbox.setAttribute('checked', true);
    } else {
      checkbox.removeAttribute('checked');
    }
  }
  checkAllButton.value = isChecked ? "Uncheck All" : "Check All";
  document.querySelector('.bike1 input').closest('div')


});
```

```html
<h1>Check & Uncheck All Options</h1>
<p>Check & Uncheck All Options by Button</p>
<input id="checkAll" type="button" value="Check All">
<div class="container-bikes" id="bike1">
  <input class="first" id="Item 1" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 1">Item 1</label>
  <input class="first" id="Item 2" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 2">Item 2</label>
</div>
<div id="bike2">
  <input class="first" id="Item 3" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 3">Item 3</label>
  <input class="first" id="Item 4" name="option1" type="checkbox">
  <label class="label1" for="Item 4">Item 4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This -> `const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#bike1 input[type=checkbox]");` - But, you should not repeat HTML Element `id` attribute values - you've used `bike1` for two different elements.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you I didn't see the doubling of `bike1`.

Comment: What is *the closest input checkboxes*? Also note, `id` values cannot contain spaces. Why does the second div not have `class="container-bikes"`?

Comment: @connexo it doesn't really need it.  I started coding something but wanted to see if I can use closest to get the closest checkboxes to loop over them and select or deselect them.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you consider *the closest checkboxes*. Please note that your ids are still invalid.

Comment: The issue has been resolved.  `const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#bike1 input[type=checkbox]");`

Answer (score 0):

`const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#bike1 input[type=checkbox]");`

All credit goes to @RandyCasburn